# Grabbing geo-location data from Instagram python

Tags: api, instagram, geo

I have instagram-python installed and  I have an oauth token from instagram api and I am trying to grab a list of all of the location data (latitude and longitude) from instagram photos posted in brussels belgium. What is the best way to do this?

Brussels is  lat: 50.85396 and long: 4.34150 and I would like to search for at least a 2km radius.

I use https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=brussels&access_token=[my access token] and it returns:

{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"media_count":387831,"name":"brussels"}, is it possible to access the data in that media_count? I want to grab as much location data as I can, I do not particularly care about the actual pictures

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the media/search API to get geolocation information around a geo location:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=50.85396&lng=4.34150&distance=2000&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

and then grab the (data[x].location.latitude, data[x].location.longitude) from the API response. Each response will give you about 20 photos, use MAX_ID param in API to get next set of 20 photo data.

Here is an implementation of exactly what you are looking for: [gramfeed](http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map?location=50.85396,4.34150)

Comment: grab the `created_time` of the last photo and pass it as `max_timestamp=` in the API url param, then u will get the next 20 photos

Comment: hi @krisrak, any idea how to get the result from a cartesian coordinates?

Comment: split the cartesian coordinates and pass it as lat= and lng=

Comment: can you show me a example? Or check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255057/get-lying-longitude-and-latitude-from-current-bound-or-cartesian-coordinates-rec?noredirect=1#comment41187007_26255057

This is what I want to do.

Comment: u can only get for circle, u can specify center and radius distance

Comment: check app.echosec.net. I want to achieve same thing.

Comment: but instagram api only allows circle

Comment: Yes, I see. But how are they using it? I am confused.

Comment: do they support instagram?

Comment: Yes, you can test it. It shows multiple result and one is Instagram

Comment: find photos in circle enclosing the boundary and then filter out the lat/lng that are outside the boundary you have.