# get lying longitude and latitude from current bound or Cartesian coordinates/Rectangle shape

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, instagram, mapbox

I am working to get Instagram results from a shape drawn on a map.
Instagram needs lat and lon + radius.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

What my issue is I can do this if I use circle but for rectangle I am not getting what to send to api.

My image/ map plus rectangle.

[image]

If I use `getBounds();`
Then I get

```
_northEast

    Object { lat=33.97980872872457, lng=-82.166748046875, equals=function(), more...}

_southWest

    Object { lat=33.568861182555565, lng=-83.5565185546875, equals=function(), more...}
```

But Api needs only one lat and lon. So can some one help what to send to api in this case?

Comment: Maybe lat and lng returned by `getBounds().getCenter()`

Comment: @Dr.Molle But I think if I make it a square with large width then it will not work with this api link?  As sending radius means a circle ( I think)

Comment: Is there any way to get all the underlying latitude and longitude of a rectangle shape?

Comment: I think this will work? http://tutorialspots.com/php-detect-point-in-polygon-506.html
 Will it work for rectangle? @Dr.Molle

Comment: There is a infinite number of latLng's for an area(no matter if it's a circle, rectangle or something else). As long as the API only supports search within a radius there is nothing you can do.

Comment: What I think is send multiple query and in result I check if the result (lat and lon) is inside the marked area (rectangle or circle) and filter the result.

Comment: Can't tell you why somebody downvotes

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Instagram API, you can ONLY send a circle. The closes equivalent would be send the [smallest enclosing circle](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Compgeometry/MyCG/CG-Applets/Center/centercli.htm)

With the Maps API, I would take a shortcut and use the following algorithim:

- Use `getBounds().getCenter()` to get the center LatLng of your rectangle. This is your LatLng.
- Use the `computeDistanceBetween` method of the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) along with either of the points from the original `getBounds()` call to calculate your radius.

Answer (score 0):

`GMSGeometryContainsLocation(coordinate, rect, true)` will work for this. Pass the object of CLLocationCoordinate2D as coordinate and and GMSPath as rect. It give Bool value. 
Thanks